# Can't scroll to top while being completely center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to make a completely centered popup menu but I can't seem to scroll all the way to the top for some reason. I think `transform` is visual only so `#content` is actually still at `top: 50%`. Is there a way for me to keep the div completely centered on `window` while being able to see everything inside `#content`?

```js
var toggle = false;
var p = document.getElementById("popup");

document.getElementById("show").onclick = function(event) {
  p.style.display = "initial";
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
};

document.getElementById("hide").onclick = function(event) {
  p.style.display = "none";
  document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
  
};
```

```css
html, body {
  margin 0;
  padding 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#popup {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  <div id="content">
    <button id="hide">Hide</button>
    <h1>Cant See</h1>
    <p>Cant SeeCant SeeCant SeeCant SeeCant SeeCant SeeCant See</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="show">Show</button>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `position: absolute` to center `#content` you can apply `display: flex` to the parent (`#popup`) and use `margin: auto`

example

```js
var toggle = false;
var p = document.getElementById("popup");

document.getElementById("show").onclick = function(event) {
  p.style.display = "flex";
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
};

document.getElementById("hide").onclick = function(event) {
  p.style.display = "none";
  document.body.style.overflow = "auto";

};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin 0;
  padding 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#popup {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  <div id="content">
    <button id="hide">Hide</button>
    <h1>Cant See</h1>
    <p>Cant SeeCant SeeCant SeeCant SeeCant SeeCant SeeCant See</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="show">Show</button>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</p>

</div>
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

adding `height: 100%` to `#content` should do the trick

Comment: This only works if `#content` is larger than `window` or without a border. But if a border is applied you can tell the div is extended to the entire window which was not what I was looking for.